# React Native and map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dictionary, components

I have an issue in my project. I want to show elements after I get them from the JSON. When I am trying to observe content of JSON I see it, but when I am trying to show it in my component it doesn't appear. Also debugger don't show any errors or problrms and app compiles sucessfully. I am really stuck, so I really need your help guys

App.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Header, ImageCard } from './src/components/uikit'

const url = 'https://s3.eu-central-1.wasabisys.com/ghashtag/RNForKids/00-Init/data.json'

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      title: 'STAR GATE',
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url)
      const data = await response.json()
      this.setState({ data })
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
      throw e

    }
  }

  render() {
    const { title, data } = this.state
    const { container } = style

    return (
      <View>
        <Header title={title} />
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={container}>
            {data.map(item => {
              <ImageCard data={item} key={item.id} />
            })
            }
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 30,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    flexShrink: 2,
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    marginBottom: 150,
    backgroundColor: 'gold',
    width: 150
  }

})
```

My problem happens in App.js inside the

And ImageCard code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Image, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { h, w } from '../../../constants'

const ImageCard = ({data}) => {
    const {container, sub, h2, cover} = styles
    const {image, name} = data
    return (
        <View style={container}>
            <View style={sub}>
                <Image
                    style={cover}
                    source={{
                        uri: image,
                    }}
                />
            </View>
            <Text style={h2}>{name.toUpperCase()}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        width: w / 2.1,
        paddingVertical: 10,
    },

    sub: {
        padding:10,
        shadowColor: 'black',
        shadowRadius: 8,
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 5 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.4,
    },

    h2: {
        fontFamily: 'AvenirNext-DemiBold',
        fontSize: 16,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        textAlign: 'center',
        width: w / 2.4
    },

    cover: {
        width: w / 2.4,
        height: w * 0.63,
        borderRadius: 10
    }
})

export { ImageCard }
```

It should be ok, I made it by guide, but something went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not returning anything from map!

```js
data.map(item => {
  <ImageCard data={item} key={item.id} />
})
```

should become

```js
data.map(item => {
  return <ImageCard data={item} key={item.id} />
})

// OR

data.map(item => ( // <-- Note the bracket change
  <ImageCard data={item} key={item.id} />
))
```

Comment: Thanks, worked! Can you also give me an advice why doesn`t my scrollview work?

Comment: @Vladimir Probably because you're rendering the ImageCards inside a View instead of directly inside the ScrollView, consider styling directly the ScrollView with `style` or `contentContainerStyle`, but I'll suggest to create a new question here to get a more complete answer!